# Is it possible to combine this javascript function into JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a function written in javascript and I'd like to know how, if it's possible, to use it in my JQuery file. I'm using the following function and my selector id is '#comments'.

Again, all I want to do is just consolidate this function which now resides in another file, into my main JQuery file. Is this possible?

```
onkeydown="textCounter(this.form.notes, this.form.remLen,240); "onkeyup="textCounter(this.form.notes, this.form.remLen, 240);"
```

The selector id is #comments.

---

```
function textCounter( field, countfield, maxlimit ){
if ( field.value.length > maxlimit )    {
    field.value = field.value.substring( 0, maxlimit );
}else{
    countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have big fat fingers. :)

Comment: jQuery = javascript. Just sayin' :-)

Comment: @Alex, What?! Really? :) Actually, I'm pretty dense with JavaScript.

Comment: I know. Sorry, I like to make the occasional stupid joke. :)

Comment: lol.. It's not stupid at all; it was funny. :) For some reason, I could never get into Javascript. I'm starting to change my tune though. Pretty cook things can be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but you can easily use your own function in these event handlers like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#comments').bind('keydown keyup', function(){
    textCounter( ...etc... );
  });
});
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might have better luck with the `keypress` event instead:

```
  $('#comments').keypress( function(){...} );
```

`Keypress` has the advantages of being triggered for every character when a key is held down for auto-repeating, and not being triggered for keys like `shift`. With `keydown` and `keyup` you'll be running your function twice for each pressed key, which may not be what you want.

---

**Update:** If all you're looking to do is truncate and show the current count, why not make a simpler function, like this:

```
function textCounter( field, countfield, limit ){
  field.value = field.value.substring(0,limit); 
  countfield.val( limit-field.value.length );
}
```

And then:

```
$('#comments').keypress( function(){
  textCounter(this, $('#bar'), 240 );
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/c5sUU/1/

Comment: Thanks Ken, I must be doing something wrong because it isn't working. Let me post my textcounter above

Comment: Thanks for the edited code Ken. I'm using this function to limit the number of allowable characters in a textarea, much like the one I'm typing you this response in now. Using your code, would I even still need the keydown events in my html>

Comment: Also, I've posted above the actual function that does the counting.

Comment: Ken, thank you. Also, thank you for taking the time to post it on JSFiddle. When I can visually see how it is laid out, I can understand it much better. Kudos my friend.

Comment: Ken, Are you still around? The counter is counting up from 0, not down from 240.

Comment: Jim, try `countfield.val( limit-field.value.length )` in the function. http://jsfiddle.net/redler/c5sUU/1/

Comment: Man, Ken, thank you so much. Now I can finally delete that javascript file that had the characterCount function in it and include this in my JQuery file. Thanks again for helping me out!

Comment: Not to open a can of worms, but of course jQuery *is* JavaScript. Presumably you're simply using a reference to a standard jQuery file (e.g. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js). There's no reason the `textCounter` function can't be organized with any of your other JavaScript code, whether in an external file or within a `<script>` region on the page in question. Likewise the bit of code in `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

yes inside the function textCounnter, add the function of the Jquery, triggering a function w/ in a function? but why do tou want the textCounter in javascript anyway?

why not do this

$(#comments){
 ..textcounter ideas inside
}

Comment: Thanks Gian, I'm a moron when it comes to JavaScript. I didn't know I could do it that way. What do you mean about having a textCounter in Javascript? What other option would there be?

Comment: i really have this option in mind.. im sure there are others.. but what im thinking is something like this